# Mule Crashes Timeout for connection

Tags: java, sockets, mule

I'm having trouble in mule service. Daily, the service crashes, about 4 times a day, making it necessary to redeploy my service.

Here's my stack trace.

```
ERROR 2016-02-04 10:30:38,063 [[app_service].NoSessionConnector.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

********************************************************************************
Message               : Timeout for connection (java.net.SocketException). Message payload is of type: HttpResponse
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Timeout for connection (java.net.SocketException)
  java.net.SocketOutputStream:-2 (null)
2. Timeout for connection (java.net.SocketException). Message payload is of type: HttpResponse (org.mule.execution.ResponseDispatchExcepti
on)
  org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageProcessTemplate:141 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/execution/ResponseDispatc
hException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketException: Tempo esgotado para conexão
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I've tried changing the number of threads in maxThreadsActive and maxBufferSize, but is still occurring the same error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the tcp connection has not been usable for a long time.

Use the the [Socket.setKeepAlive()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive(boolean)) or apply the [heart beat mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19206-01/816-4178/6madjde6e/index.html).